# у меня есть код для змейки, но break выдает ошибку can be used only within a loop как пофиксить?

Tags: python

```
import time
import turtle
from random import randrange

BREAK_FLAG = False
# draw a window for the game
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title('Snake with turtle module')
screen.bgcolor('orange')
screen.setup(650, 650)
screen.tracer(0)
# draw a game field border
border = turtle.Turtle()
border.hideturtle()
border.penup()
border.goto(-311, 311)
border.pendown()
border.goto(311, 311)
border.goto(311, -311)
border.goto(-311, -311)
border.goto(-311, 311)
# draw a snake of three segments and
# paint the head of the snake in black
snake = []
    for i in range(3):
    snake_segment = turtle.Turtle()
    snake_segment.shape('square')
    snake_segment.penup()
    if i > 0:
        snake_segment.color('gray')
    snake.append(snake_segment)
    # draw a food for the snake
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.shape('circle')
food.penup()
food.goto(randrange(-300, 300, 20), randrange(-300, 300, 20))
# snake control
screen.onkeypress(lambda: snake[0].setheading(90), 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(lambda: snake[0].setheading(270), 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(lambda: snake[0].setheading(180), 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(lambda: snake[0].setheading(0), 'Right')
screen.listen()
 # creating a new segment of the snake
    # and redraw a food for the snake
if snake[0].distance(food) < 10:
        food.goto(randrange(-300, 300, 20), randrange(-300, 300, 20))
        snake_segment = turtle.Turtle()
        snake_segment.shape('square')
        snake_segment.color('gray')
        snake_segment.penup()
        snake.append(snake_segment)
 # snake body movement
for i in range(len(snake)-1, 0, -1):
        x = snake[i-1].xcor()
        y = snake[i-1].ycor()
        snake[i].goto(x, y) 
# snake head movement
snake[0].forward(20)
screen.update() 
# snake collision with border
x_cor = snake[0].xcor()
y_cor = snake[0].ycor()
if x_cor > 300 or x_cor < -300:
    screen.bgcolor('red')
    break
if y_cor > 300 or y_cor < -300:
    screen.bgcolor('red')
    break
    # snake collision with itself
    for i in snake[1:]:
        i = i.position()
        if snake[0].distance(i) < 10:
                    BREAK_FLAG = True
                    if BREAK_FLAG:
                        screen.bgcolor('red')
                    break
       time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: пофиксить - ввести цикл чтобы из него можно было выходить через break :)

Comment: можеш написать как именно?

Comment: утоните, что по вашему делает break ? для чего он в вашем коде ? и ещё важный момент, вы уверены что у вас отступы правильные ? для питона это важно

Comment: @Интик, с отступами там вообще беда, на счет брейков - такое чувство, что код взят из более большого кода

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/133055/ вот откуда код

Comment: а отступы я немного менял т.к вылазили ошибки

Comment: не правильно поменяли, переделывайте.и недостощий кусок добавьте. https://github.com/YuriyCherniy/snake-with-turtle-module/blob/master/snake.py

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, break просто надо сдвинуть (вправо на одну TAB или влево - на несколько):

```
if BREAK_FLAG:
   screen.bgcolor('red')
   break
```

Comment: и чтоже этот break прерывает ? вон по ссылке оригинальный код. и в вопросе пропущен основной цикл while True: